# Electromagnetic radiation exposure power density per wavelength

Tags: electromagnetism, radiation

Does anyone know a theoretical study or an experimental study of the electromagnetic ambient power density at different wavelengths? To ask simply, how much electromagnetism are human usually exposed to?

Indoors, I am thinking lighting, appliances, thermal, solar, wireless communications, wired devices, building materials all contribute to electromagnetic radiation exposure. Outdoors, the sun and other extraterrestrial sources are probably relatively more significant. What sources do we have to consider in theory? Has this been measured in practice?

And if anyone wants to expand the answer, what non photon sources of radiation are we exposed to and can we characterize those as well? And for these sources, is power density still appropriate?

And also as a more difficult but maybe necessary question, because the exposure is so variable depending on when and where a person is located, what is a good way to characterize all of this variable spectrum?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.